# Whether to use the detectCores function in R to specify the number of cores for parallel processing?

Tags: r, parallel-processing

In the [help](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/html/detectCores.html) for `detectCores()` it says:

> **This is not suitable for** use directly for the mc.cores argument of
>   mclapply nor **specifying the number of cores in makeCluster**. First
>   because it may return NA, and second because it does not give the
>   number of allowed cores.

However, I've seen quite a bit of sample code like the following:

```
library(parallel)
k <- 1000
m <- lapply(1:7, function(X) matrix(rnorm(k^2), nrow=k))

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1, type = "FORK")
test <- parLapply(cl, m, solve)
stopCluster(cl)
```

where `detectCores()` is used to specify the number of cores in `makeCluster`.

My use cases involve running parallel processing both on my own multicore laptop (OSX) and running it on various multicore servers (Linux). So, I wasn't sure whether there is a better way to specify the number of cores or whether perhaps that advice about not using `detectCores` was more for package developers where code is meant to run over a wide range of hardware and OS environments.

So in summary:

- **Should you use the `detectCores` function in R to specify the number of cores for parallel processing?**
- **What is the distinction mean between detected and allowed cores and when is it relevant?**

Comment: what platform are you on? `system('getconf _NPROCESSORS_ONLN')`

Comment: Both OSX and Linux; I've updated my question to state this; although I guess I'm interested in the general answer to make this useful for others.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think it's perfectly reasonable to use `detectCores` as a starting point for the number of workers/processes when calling `mclapply` or `makeCluster`. However, there are many reasons that you may want or need to start fewer workers, and even some cases where you can reasonably start more.

On some hyperthreaded machines it may not be a good idea to set `mc.cores=detectCores()`, for example.  Or if your script is running on an HPC cluster, you shouldn't use any more resources than the job scheduler has allocated to your job. You also have to be careful in nested parallel situations, as when your code may be executed in parallel by a calling function, or you're executing a multithreaded function in parallel.  In general, it's a good idea to run some preliminary benchmarks before starting a long job to determine the best number of workers. I usually monitor the benchmark with `top` to see if the number of processes and threads makes sense, and to verify that the memory usage is reasonable.

The advice that you quoted is particularly appropriate for package developers.  It's certainly a bad idea for a package developer to always start `detectCores()` workers when calling `mclapply` or `makeCluster`, so it's best to leave the decision up to the end user.  At least the package should allow the user to specify the number of workers to start, but arguably `detectCores()` isn't even a good default value.  That's why the default value for `mc.cores` changed from `detectCores()` to `getOptions("mc.cores", 2L)` when `mclapply` was included in the `parallel` package.

I think the real point of the warning that you quoted is that R functions should not assume that they own the whole machine, or that they are the only function in your script that is using multiple cores.  If you call `mclapply` with `mc.cores=detectCores()` in a package that you submit to CRAN, I expect your package will be rejected until you change it. But if you're the end user, running a parallel script on your own machine, then it's up to you to decide how many cores the script is allowed to use.

Comment: So if I don't own the machine and I've been given fewer cores per node than available, how can I use `detectCores()` or something similar to make sure I only use the allowed cores? In that case, should I just put it in manually?

Comment: @Plinth In that case, `detectCores()` isn't much use. If you're using a batch queueing system, you can usually use an environment variable to determine how many cores per node have been allocated to your job. On Torque, you could count the node names listed in $PBS_NODEFILE using something like `table(readLines(Sys.getenv('PBS_NODEFILE')))`. But in general you might have to specify this information as a command line argument to your R script.

Comment: Didn't want to complicate things too much in my `future::availableCores()` answer, but `future::availableWorkers()` parses known HPC files such as `PBS_NODEFILE` that Steve mentions.  I think this should only be needed for multi-node jobs and I believe `PBS_NUM_PPN` is always set (happy to be corrected / learn otherwise).

Answer (score 11):

Author of the [parallelly](https://cran.r-project.org/package=parallelly) package here: The `parallelly::availableCores()` function acknowledges various HPC environment variables (e.g. `NSLOTS`, `PBS_NUM_PPN`, and `SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK`) and system and R settings that are used to specify the number of cores available to the process, and if not specified, it'll fall back to `parallel::detectCores()`.  As I, or others, become aware of more settings, I'll be happy to add automatic support also for those; there is an always open GitHub issue for this over at https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/parallelly/issues/17 (there are some open requests for help).

Also, if the sysadm sets environment variable `R_PARALLELLY_AVAILABLECORES_FALLBACK=1` sitewide, then `parallelly::availableCores()` will return 1, unless explicitly overridden by other means (by the job scheduler, by the user settings, ...).  This further protects against software tools taking over all cores by default.

In other words, if you use `parallelly::availableCores()` rather than `parallel::detectCores()` you can be fairly sure that your code plays nice in multi-tenant environments (if it turns out it's not enough, please let us know in the above GitHub issue) and that any end user can still control the number of cores without you having to change your code.

EDIT 2021-07-26: `availableCores()` was moved from [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) to [parallelly](https://cran.r-project.org/package=parallelly) in October 2020.  For now and for backward compatible reasons, `availableCores()` function is re-exported by the 'future' package.

Answer (score 1):

Better in my case (I use mac) is `future::availableCores()` because `detectCores()` shows 160 which is obviously wrong.